# Android project as library to another project on github

Tags: android, git, reference

Now I have two projects one is like model and another is like view. Now I use it in eclipse and model is used as library for view. But now I need to move this projects on Github. But I don't want every time to checkout both projects. Is there any way how to do it easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easy but wrong

Most Android library projects which contain a Library and a Sample project have done the following:

1. Put them both in a empty folder (eg. your workspace)
2. Call **git init** in that folder, normally this is called within the project itself.

### The right way

As indicated by the titles, the method above is not the normal way,

You should take a look at [Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules),

which is the standard procedure for having multiple projects with git